# ZBarSDK don't dismiss the viewController

Tags: ios, dismiss, zbar-sdk

I am using the ZBarSDK (http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/) in my app. It works fine and very fast but I have found an issue.
I get this warning in the console and the scanner viewController never dismiss. It happens only when I try to scan a barcode that I've already have focused. I mean, when I press the button that open the reader viewController and then focus the camera where the barcode is, it works fine, the viewController dissapear and I get the code. But the problem is when I've already have focussed the iPad to the barcode and then I press the reader button. The reader viewController is presented, I get the code, but the viewController is not dismissed and I get this warning:

**Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller  while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!**

This is the code used:

```
- (void)escanearCodigo
{
    ZBarReaderViewController *escanearVC = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
    escanearVC.readerDelegate = self;
    escanearVC.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;

    // Presentar pantalla escaneo
    [self presentViewController:escanearVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
{
    // Obtener el resultado del escaneo
    id<NSFastEnumeration> results = [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];
    ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;
    for(symbol in results)
        //Almacenar el codigo de barras
        break;

    NSLog(@"Code: %@", symbol.data);

    [reader dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I hope I have explained well :)

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATED:**
Until now, the best "half-solution" is the next:
Put the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo code inside an if sentence to prevent this code will be exec when the viewController is no presented yet (I think):

```
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
{
    if (![reader isBeingPresented]) {
        // Obtener el resultado del escaneo
        id<NSFastEnumeration> results = [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];
        ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;
        for(symbol in results)
            //Almacenar el codigo de barras
            break;

        [reader dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    }

}
```

Comment: Is the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo ` method beeing called when the viewcontroller is not being dismissed? Have you tested it with i.e. NSLog?

Comment: thanks! I have write the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo inside if(![reader isBeingPresented]) and the warning dissapear, but I need to focus another area (without barcode) and then focus to the barcode area to scan it. Until now this is the best solution :) thank u!

Comment: try flushing the cache of the ZBarReaderView whenever presenting ZBarreaderViewcontroller *[escanearVC.readerView flushCache];*

Answer (score 1):

> ... but I need to focus another area (without barcode) and then focus to the barcode area to scan it.

Since the warning relates to the presentation and dismissal of your ZBarReaderViewController, you should only encapsulate the `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` call in an if-else-block. This is to prevent ZBars performance from being affected as you described. Additionally, you can delay the call in case the presentation could not yet finish.

For example:

```
if (![reader isBeingPresented]) {
    [self dismissReader];
}else{
    [self performSelector:@selector(dismissReader) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.7];
}
```

and then in `[self dismissReader]`:

```
- (void) dismissReader
  {
      [_reader dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
  }
```

**Note**: the delay time of 0.7 seconds is arbitrary and may vary depending on the duration of the animation.